# Smooth Scroll plugin not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scroll, smoothing

So I have come to the completion of my website, and have just discovered that the smooth scrolling JS I was using wont work in Chrome. It works perfectly in Safari, Firefox and  I have tried others, but I can't seem to get them to recognise my anchors, or maintain the highlighted nav.

This is my nav:

```
<ul id="menu"><!-- BEGIN MENU -->
    <li><img class="valigner"><a href="#home">home</a></li>
    <li><img class="valigner"><a href="#about">about</a></li>
    <li><img class="valigner"><a href="#headshots">headshots</a></li>
    <li><img class="valigner"><a href="#fashion">fashion</a></li>
    <li><img class="valigner"><a href="#editorial">editorial</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home"><img src="img/logo.jpg" class="logo"/></a></li>
    <li><img class="valigner"><a href="#live">live</a></li>
    <li><img class="valigner"><a href="#events">events</a></li>
    <li><img class="valigner"><a href="#outside">outside</a></li>
    <li><img class="valigner"><a href="#product">product</a></li>
    <li><img class="valigner"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
</ul><!-- END MENU -->
```

this is the JS:

```
;(function( $ ){

var $scrollTo = $.scrollTo = function( target, duration, settings ){
    $(window).scrollTo( target, duration, settings );
};

$scrollTo.defaults = {
    axis:'xy',
    duration: parseFloat($.fn.jquery) >= 1.3 ? 0 : 1
};

// Returns the element that needs to be animated to scroll the window.
// Kept for backwards compatibility (specially for localScroll & serialScroll)
$scrollTo.window = function( scope ){
    return $(window)._scrollable();
};

// Hack, hack, hack :)
// Returns the real elements to scroll (supports window/iframes, documents and regular nodes)
$.fn._scrollable = function(){
    return this.map(function(){
        var elem = this,
            isWin = !elem.nodeName || $.inArray( elem.nodeName.toLowerCase(), ['iframe','#document','html','body'] ) != -1;

            if( !isWin )
                return elem;

        var doc = (elem.contentWindow || elem).document || elem.ownerDocument || elem;

        return $.browser.safari || doc.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ?
            doc.body : 
            doc.documentElement;
    });
};

$.fn.scrollTo = function( target, duration, settings ){
    if( typeof duration == 'object' ){
        settings = duration;
        duration = 0;
    }
    if( typeof settings == 'function' )
        settings = { onAfter:settings };

    if( target == 'max' )
        target = 9e9;

    settings = $.extend( {}, $scrollTo.defaults, settings );
    // Speed is still recognized for backwards compatibility
    duration = duration || settings.speed || settings.duration;
    // Make sure the settings are given right
    settings.queue = settings.queue && settings.axis.length > 1;

    if( settings.queue )
        // Let's keep the overall duration
        duration /= 60000;
    settings.offset = both( settings.offset );
    settings.over = both( settings.over );

    return this._scrollable().each(function(){
        var elem = this,
            $elem = $(elem),
            targ = target, toff, attr = {},
            win = $elem.is('html,body');

        switch( typeof targ ){
            // A number will pass the regex
            case 'number':
            case 'string':
                if( /^([+-]=)?\d+(\.\d+)?(px|%)?$/.test(targ) ){
                    targ = both( targ );
                    // We are done
                    break;
                }
                // Relative selector, no break!
                targ = $(targ,this);
            case 'object':
                // DOMElement / jQuery
                if( targ.is || targ.style )
                    // Get the real position of the target 
                    toff = (targ = $(targ)).offset();
        }
        $.each( settings.axis.split(''), function( i, axis ){
            var Pos = axis == 'x' ? 'Left' : 'Top',
                pos = Pos.toLowerCase(),
                key = 'scroll' + Pos,
                old = elem[key],
                max = $scrollTo.max(elem, axis);

            if( toff ){// jQuery / DOMElement
                attr[key] = toff[pos] + ( win ? 0 : old - $elem.offset()[pos] );

                // If it's a dom element, reduce the margin
                if( settings.margin ){
                    attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('margin'+Pos)) || 0;
                    attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('border'+Pos+'Width')) || 0;
                }

                attr[key] += settings.offset[pos] || 0;

                if( settings.over[pos] )
                    // Scroll to a fraction of its width/height
                    attr[key] += targ[axis=='x'?'width':'height']() * settings.over[pos];
            }else{ 
                var val = targ[pos];
                // Handle percentage values
                attr[key] = val.slice && val.slice(-1) == '%' ? 
                    parseFloat(val) / 100 * max
                    : val;
            }

            // Number or 'number'
            if( /^\d+$/.test(attr[key]) )
                // Check the limits
                attr[key] = attr[key] <= 0 ? 0 : Math.min( attr[key], max );

            // Queueing axes
            if( !i && settings.queue ){
                // Don't waste time animating, if there's no need.
                if( old != attr[key] )
                    // Intermediate animation
                    animate( settings.onAfterFirst );
                // Don't animate this axis again in the next iteration.
                delete attr[key];
            }
        });

        animate( settings.onAfter );            

        function animate( callback ){
            $elem.animate( attr, duration, settings.easing, callback && function(){
                callback.call(this, target, settings);
            });
        };

    }).end();
};

// Max scrolling position, works on quirks mode
// It only fails (not too badly) on IE, quirks mode.
$scrollTo.max = function( elem, axis ){
    var Dim = axis == 'x' ? 'Width' : 'Height',
        scroll = 'scroll'+Dim;

    if( !$(elem).is('html,body') )
        return elem[scroll] - $(elem)[Dim.toLowerCase()]();

    var size = 'client' + Dim,
        html = elem.ownerDocument.documentElement,
        body = elem.ownerDocument.body;

    return Math.max( html[scroll], body[scroll] ) 
         - Math.min( html[size]  , body[size]   );

};

function both( val ){
    return typeof val == 'object' ? val : { top:val, left:val };
};

})( jQuery );
```

I believe it came from Ariel Flesler but his demo page and documentation just confused me more.

Comment: are there any errors on the console?

Comment: No, nothing. And it works perfectly fine in Safari and Firefox

Comment: Spreading dead links is never a good point... Use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) instead!

Answer (score 2):

this work on all of browsers ,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //run once
        var el = $('#Container');
        var originalelpos = el.offset().top; // take it where it originally is on the page

        //run on scroll
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var el = $('#Container'); // important! (local)
            var elpos = el.offset().top; // take current situation
            var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
            var finaldestination = windowpos + originalelpos;
            el.css('top', finaldestination);
            //el.stop().animate({ 'top': finaldestination }, 1000);
        });

    });
```

I hope that will help , you can use animate for animating or .css for changing the top attr in style

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong in my my reference or anchors?

Comment: The $('#Container'); should be changed by the div that u want to scroll all over your webpage # is for id , you use the Container as a Class , i Used it as a id

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more concise:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu a').bind("click", function(e) {
        var target = $(this).attr("href"); // Get the target element
        var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top; // Position to scroll to
        $('html /* For FF & IE */,body /* For Chrome */').animate({
            'scrollTop': scrollToPosition 
        }, 500, function(target){
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[See it in action!](http://jsfiddle.net/trojansdestroy/gQDsC/)